# Spring MVC x wildfly 17 x logbackconfiguration

Tags: spring-mvc, logging, logback, wildfly-17

So I have a project for which I need to set up logback. This project is strictly spring MVC(can't be upgraded to spring-boot). It is deployed on wildfly 17.0.1.

I have a few questions regarding this.

1. So I did the setup of logback and logs are generated fine. But auto scan of the configuration file *logback.xml* is not working.

###### My setup

This is the only dependency I've added to my project. Logback is set up to bridge via slf4j(set up in wildfly)

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my logback.xml file.

```
<configuration scan="true" scan_period="2 seconds" debug="false" packagingData="false">

  <property name="PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
  <property name="LOG_DIR" value="path/to/dir" />

 

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/server.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
<!--      <level>INFO</level>-->
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/server.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>365</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>${PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="APP_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/app.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
<!--      <level>INFO</level>-->
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/uix.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>365</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>${PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ACCESS_APP_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/access.app.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
<!--      <level>INFO</level>-->
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/access.app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>365</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>${PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>


  
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
      </encoder>
    </appender>
  </root>


  <logger name="com.package.path" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ACCESS_APP_FILE"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="com.package.path.2" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="APP_FILE"/>
  </logger>


</configuration>
```

This *logback.xml* file is placed in wildfly's standalone folder for me to be able to change the runtime log level(reference to *logback.xml* is given in *standalone.sh*). But this is not working and after searching for it, people suggested putting it in the target folder which does not make sense(since I then can't change the log level once **.war* is deployed).

So can someone suggest what can be done here where I can achieve changing log level at runtime?

2. The console Appender does not work at all. Logs that are supposed to be seen in the console, are stored in a log file. But I also want them to be displayed on the console too. I'm using the same configuration file as above. Can you help me with this too?

###### Things I've done

- Added *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* and excluded other logging libraries from wildfly or even my own project.
- Setting LogContext and setting configuration file in the project which also didn't work.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Is logback a requirement? Also I'd HIGHLY recommend you do not create a `server.log` file or you'll lose all of the servers logging.

Comment: Any other logging library would also be fine unless it has any vulnerability. But I see logback is used widely now and is replacing log4j. log4j2 also has the same kind of configuration as logback, so I decided to go with a better one.
if ```server.log``` file is created, the logs are stored in it. When I abruptly stop wildfly, it still stores the log in the ```server.log``` in secondary memory. So I'm not sure as to why ```server.log``` is not a good idea to store wildfly logs.

Comment: WildFly uses the jboss-logmanager which is an extension of JUL. You can configure logging through the logging subsystem in WildFly. By default there is a `periodic-rotating-file-handler` for the `server.log` so you'll have two writers attempting to write to the same file.

Comment: I have removed every bit of default logging configuration that Jboss provides(removing logging subsystem) to make sure that only logback is being used via slf4j. I directly made slf4j use logback as well. So There is only one logging library working to write logs. Also in ```jboss-deployment-structure```, all other libraries are excluded from loading. So JUL won't be loaded and writing logs to any file.

Comment: The server will not write messages to log back without some serious hacking of internals. It essentially requires the jboss-logmanager